# groovy: How to mock/stub a collaborator's getter and make it return a stub

Tags: groovy, mocking

I'm writing a test with groovy and wonder how to stub an interface that is a collaborator's collaborator (from my class under test (CUT) point-of-view).

project.logger would return an instance of the interface org.gradle.api.Project.Logger, and logger is the getter I'd need to mock.

Any ideas how to create a Logger without implementing the Logger interface and make my cut instance return it?
I guess I'm missing something as I'm quite new to mock testing.

Thanks
Jan

The TestCase:

```
import org.gradle.api.Project

class MyClassUnderTestTestCase{
    @Test
    void testDoSomething(){
        StubFor projectStub = new StubFor(Project)
        projectStub.demand.getLogger { } // create a Logger stub here?

        projectStub.use {
            def project = { } as Project
            MyClassUnderTest cut = new MyClassUnderTest(project)
            cut.doSomething()
            //Further assertions
        }
        projectStub.expect.verify()
    }
}
```

My CUT:

```
import org.gradle.api.Project

class MyClassUnderTest{
    private Project project

    MyClassUnderTest(Project project){
        this.project = project
    }

    void doSomething(){
        project.logger.info "Start doing something..."    // project.logger should now return a stubbed instance of Logger
        //Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost! You just have to use the logger stub too:

```
class MyClassUnderTestTestCase{
    @Test
    void testDoSomething(){
        // Stubbing interface!
        StubFor loggerStub = new StubFor(Logger)
        loggerStub.demand.info { msg -> println "Mocked $msg" }
        // Logger interface proxy
        Logger loggerProxy = loggerStub.proxyInstance()

        // Stubbing interface!
        StubFor projectStub = new StubFor(Project)
        projectStub.demand.getLogger { loggerProxy }
        // Project proxy instance
        Project projectProxy = projectStub.proxyInstance()

        // Inject the proxy instance of Project
        MyClassUnderTest cut = new MyClassUnderTest(projectProxy)
        cut.doSomething()

        // Verify the proxy interaction
        projectStub.verify(projectProxy)
    }
}
```

If you are using interface, you need to get the implementation of the interface by using proxyInstance().

And I have one suggestion for groovy developers for unit testing, check this awesome framework: [spock framework](http://spockframework.org/)!

Comment: Cool, I didn't know I could nest the stub.use closures.
But I'm getting a NullPointer now:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method info() on null object

 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)`

Comment: Maybe If you change {} as Project to new Project()? I did some testing here and it's the only difference between your code and mine.

Comment: Project and Logger are interfaces, I cannot instantiate it a new Project.
I'd like to leverage the fact that I do not have to provide dummy implementations of those or search for implementation classes to instantiate, as these interfaces are really heavy (implementing both classes sums up to 1000 loc)

Comment: I updated the answer! Now I'm using Project and Logger as interface. Note that you need the implementation to be passed to CUT, so you get the proxy from the stub and you need to verify the proxy interaction now. Good coding!

Comment: The call proxyInstance() was the crucial hint. Thanks Rafael!